# Matlab GUI, two listbox, pass the data from listbox1 to listbox2 and appending to the older data

Tags: matlab, user-interface

In listbox1, I have a number of data, now I select some of them and click push button, those selected data can be shown in listbox2. Then I go on selecting data in listbox1 and clicking push button, the old data in listbox2 disappear and new data is shown in listbox2. here comes the code in callback funcion:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   list_entries = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
   index_selected = get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
   Length = length(index_selected);
   Newlist = list_entries;
   for i=1:Length
      n = index_selected(i);
      handles.element(i) = list_entries(n)
      if i==1
         Newlist(n) = []
      else
         Newlist(n-1) = []
      end
   end

   set(handles.listbox1,'String',Newlist);
   set(handles.listbox2,'String',handles.element);
```

Help me to solve this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to replace the data in a listbox (i.e. the String) by some other string, you don't have to go through the process of actually deleting the old data. You can simply assign the String from listbox 1 to listbox 2 and you're good to go.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

set(handles.listbox2,'String',get(handles.listbox1,'String'));
```

**EDIT** Following your comment, it seems that you want to append new data/string (from listbox 1) to the existing string in listbox 2. You can concatenate the cell array of strings easily as follows:

Let's say the strings in listbox 1 and listbox 2 are obtained as usual:

```
String1 = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
String2 = get(handles.listbox2,'String');
```

For example `String1 = {'A' 'B' 'C'}` and `String2 = {'D' 'E' 'F'}`

then you can concatenate the cell arrays and set the string property of listbox2 like so:

```
NewString = [String1 String2]
```

giving this:

```
NewString = 

    'A'    'B'    'C'    'D'    'E'    'F'
```

So then use this

```
set(handles.listbox2,'String',NewString);
```

and you're good to go.

Hope it's okay now.

Comment: no, I do not simply want to replace. I wanna add the selected items in boxlist1 to boxlist2. The user will select any of the items and pass them to listbox2.

Comment: And here is another question: if i select all the data in listbox1 and push the button, the listbox just disappear. do you know how comes this?

Comment: mhh nope that's not supposed to happen. Maybe you used an assignment such as set(handles...] = [] as above and it deleted the listbox? Or you set the 'visible' property to 'off' maybe?

Comment: Oh I have solved this. add this and the end: set(handles.listbox1,'Value',1);